# How to store the properties of the goods in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, entity-attribute-value

Now I'm planning the structure of the database products. There was a question of storage options / parameters of the goods.
For example, if it were the size of the goods - it would be enough to create three fields to the width / height / depth, but what if dozens of parameters?
It is assumed that the list of parameters can be changed and I see about this structure:
    1 - width
    2 - height
    ...
    11 - color

but I can not tie it like a commodity - it is possible to make the field with json type

{1: "20", 2 "30", ..., 11: "white"}
and then treated at a sample of the goods, but I do not know how then do filter parameters

who can advise on the right path?

Comment: See my [_EAV blog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thing can be achieved with three methods

1. Adding all `separate columns` in the `products table`.
2. Adding an `extras` column with longtext type at end of `products table` to store all extra/dynamic parameters in it by **json-encoding** or **serializing**.
3. Last one is to use a separate meta table for storing key,value pair alongwith product_id in that table.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE product_meta()
       id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  // Primary key of this table
       product_id INT, // For joining purpose and reference
       meta_key VARCHAR(16),
       meta_value VARCHAR(64)
   );
   ```

So then for product ID 137, you might have several records:

```
|------------------------------------------|
| id   | product_id | meta_key | meta_value|
|------------------------------------------|
| 3137 | 137        | size     | large     |
| 3138 | 137        | color    | green     |
| 3139 | 137        | height   | 11.3      |
|------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Serializing it won't work - it makes it almost impossible to do any sort of decent filtering (which was part of the question). You'd either have to deserialize every column at runtime, or use complicated regex. That's why I didn't include it as an option.

Comment: You can do filtering by joining `product_meta table` with `products table`. You can do filtering for separate columns as well but not possible as such when storing in JSON without regular expressions or somehow with `like` expression.

Answer (score 1):

There's basically two ways to do it - you can create a series of "udf" (User Defined Field) columns in your table, like udf1, udf2, etc - then somewhere else in your app you say that "udf1 == color, udf2 == weight".

Another way would be to create a productmeta table, that had a structure like:

```
id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
product_id INT
property VARCHAR(16)
propvalue VARCHAR(64)
```

So then for product ID 137, you might have several records:

```
|------------------------------------------|
| ID   | product_id | property | propvalue |
|------------------------------------------|
| 3137 | 137        | size     | large     |
| 3138 | 137        | color    | green     |
| 3139 | 137        | height   | 11.3      |
|------------------------------------------|
```

The downside is that these tables can get really big, really fast.

Comment: Thank you. I hope you will not take offense for what I will choose the first valid response

Comment: @DmitriySkogorev Seeing as it's more or less exactly identical to my reply, that's fine ;)